# Why is CORS working? I expected it to fail

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome-extension, cors

I want to understand how CORS is working in this case without any server side configuration on my part (full network timeline screenshot below)

I'm working on a [web app](https://github.com/iampeterbanjo/lose-clients-annoy-coworkers/commit/f7f1f440a9fadbe6c213ce380c7b047435e6fc8d) that started out as a Chrome extension prototype. It has a chrome manifest like this

```
{
    "name": "How to lose clients and annoy coworkers",
    "description": "Useful tips for more unproductive living",
    "version": "0.2",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    },
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "chrome_style": true
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/all-skin-types-16x16.png",
        "48": "images/all-skin-types-48x48.png",
        "128": "images/all-skin-types-128x128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "https://sheetsu.com/apis/2e55358e/*"
    ]
}
```

I then decided to make it into a web based app expecting to have to solve the issue of making requests to `https://sheetsu.com/apis/2e55358e/*` which is a [Google Spreadsheet backend](https://sheetsu.com/). But it works without any changes in Chrome and Firefox. I tried to make another request to Twitter and that failed.

I thought maybe it was because of the `[Chrome extension manifest.json][3]` but when I added `https://twitter.com` to the permissions list, it still failed.

[image]

And I was also able to make a POST request to `https://sheetsu.com/apis/2e55358e`

Comment: I don't understand. Your request shows it comes from a web origin, what does it have to do with the extension's manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` @ `https://sheetsu.com/apis/2e55358e` has your domain listed (`iampeterbanjo.github.io`) but `twitter.com` does not.

Comment: I checked with the author of sheetsu and it has a wildcard Access-Control-Allow-Origin :-)